# Using OData for user Authentication in java

Tags: java, http, authentication, odata, odata4j

I am new to OData. I am creating an application in which I have to create both front-end and back-end. For the communication of back-end and front-end I have to use OData. In my application before accessing any data I need to first authenticate the user. In back-end i am maintaining userid/password. I want to know that Is OData protocol can be used for user authentication? I have idea how to perform user authentication when protocol is simple http but OData stuff is new to me. I just want to clarify that OData is a good way for user authentication or not.